# Joining tables with dynamic sets of data

Tags: t-sql, function, view, common-table-expression

In my query I want to join a dynamic set (retrieved based on parameters) of data with the existing table. I was researching what would be the best option to complete this scenario and I ended narrowing down to 3 options.

View, CTE, function, CTE+function

Query would look something like

```
select id from table
where id not in (select id from dynamic_set (param1, param2) )
```

- With view I have to pull all the data without being able to filter it.
- Function will have to run for each row in table, so it might influence query performance.
- Combination of CTE and function is pretty much the same as using the function itself, only the rows could be filtered and optimized for slightly better performance.
- CTE is simillar to temp table, so my question is would large set of data influcence performance

I would like to hear your opinion about the best possible solution

Thanks for participating

Comment: "With view I have to pull all the data without being able to filter it." This is false, unless the view has a clustered index.

Comment: "CTE is simillar to temp table" this is false also.

Comment: @AdrianIftode: By "pull all the data" I meant that any advanced logic has to be recreated inside main query in order to refine view and join it with an original table. I was looking for a solution that would we object oriented, and view is not such a solution.

Comment: TSQL is not object oriented..

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Not sure what is actually your point in participating in this topic, since you did not have a single comment towards solution. I am fully aware that SQL is not OODBMS, but I was referring to an reusable solution. Clear now?

Comment: I answered what reusable solutions you do have. Actually all of them are reusable. A view is reusable in other queries, a CTE is reusable in a single query definition, a function is reusable also, but it might hurt the performance. Really, I don't want to argue with you, that wasn't my intention at all.

Answer (score 2):

A view doesn't pull all data, it is more like a named query available to be used with another queries. When a view is filtered it just adds that filter to the query defined in that view.

A CTE query is more like a local view, it can be referenced only where it is defined ( after ;with). Also this is not materialized and I don't know any way to materialize a CTE query, like we can do with views (by adding a clustered index).

A function is the worst option, you said it why. I would choose the CTE way if the "inline" query is going to be used only here.

Comment: Does SQL Server support something like [Oracle's Scalar Subquery Caching](http://lukaseder.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/oracle-scalar-subquery-caching/)? That would need to be considered for using functions, too. Although, with most functions, you would still be right as functions cannot be transformed as powerfully as SQL by the optimiser